# I receive An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is the error I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C: \Users\Lee Chern Hao\Desktop\2017 folder sem 2\sensor\Mid term projectv2\sntp project\sntp project\App_Data\shoppingcart.mdf failed.
>   A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

This is my connection string used:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\Lee Chern Hao\Desktop\2017 folder sem 2\sensor\Mid term projectv2\sntp project\sntp project\App_Data\shoppingcart.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

Answer (score 3):

The message telling you this, with out testing it, you have an extra space af C:

```
AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\
```

Contains space after C:, it should be

```
AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\
```

Comment: ty for your help